# Getting cpu_limits for accounts at a specified block height

Tags: cpu, dfuse

I need to query cpu_available for a bunch of users at some specified block height. I'm trying to use the dfuse api but by querying the userres table, I get only cpu_weight. Is there any way I can get the cpu_available for a user at a particular block height?

Comment: Is there any table within EOS giving the `CPU Available` value?

Comment: I couldn't find any

Answer (score 1):

This is a dynamic value that changes according to network conditions.

As of today, `dfuse` doesn't offer available CPU at any block height.